# Java: Wrong variable increasing?

Tags: java, variables, if-statement, for-loop, increment

This little snippet of code for some reason isn't working properly. What this is supposed to do is make a move if `i` is less than `colLength`, which is 2 at this point meaning it should stop after typing in 7. And for some reason it keeps going until the end of the array.

Why does it keep going? I don't have any bit of code that increments `r`?

```
//this is a 5 step process, this is the 4th
if (stepMaker == 4 && numLocation < totalSteps){ 
    //looking through the array for the last number used in step 3, this works
    for (int r = 0; r < gridRow-1; r++){ 
        for (int c = 0; c < gridCol-1; c++){ // still looking
            //using 5 instead of numLocation works, numLocation keeps going however... why?
            if(grid[r][c] == (numLocation)) {
                int x = 1;
                for(int i = 0; i < colLength; i++){ 
                    grid[r + x][c] = numLocation + 1; 
                    System.out.println("x=" + x + " // " +
                                       "numLocation=" + numLocation + " // " +
                                       "r=" + r + " // " +
                                       "c=" + c + " // " +
                                       "stepMaker=" + stepMaker + " // " + 
                                       "colLength=" + colLength + " // " +
                                       "rowLength=" + rowLength);
                    numLocation++;
                    for (int xx = 0; xx < gridRow; xx++){
                        for (int yy = 0; yy < gridCol; yy++){
                            System.out.print(grid[xx][yy] + " ");
                        }
                        System.out.println("");
                    }
                    x++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    //colLength++;
    stepMaker++;
}
```

And this is the output:

```
x=1 // numLocation=5 // r=2 // c=2 // stepMaker=4 // colLength=2 // rowLength=3
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 5 4 3 0 0 
0 0 6 1 2 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
x=2 // numLocation=6 // r=2 // c=2 // stepMaker=4 // colLength=2 // rowLength=3
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 5 4 3 0 0 
0 0 6 1 2 0 0 
0 0 7 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
x=1 // numLocation=7 // r=4 // c=2 // stepMaker=4 // colLength=2 // rowLength=3
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 5 4 3 0 0 
0 0 6 1 2 0 0 
0 0 7 0 0 0 0 
0 0 8 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
x=2 // numLocation=8 // r=4 // c=2 // stepMaker=4 // colLength=2 // rowLength=3
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 5 4 3 0 0 
0 0 6 1 2 0 0 
0 0 7 0 0 0 0 
0 0 8 0 0 0 0 
0 0 9 0 0 0 0 
rowLength = 3   //   colLength = 2
```

Comment: then what about  `for (int r = 0; r < gridRow-1; r++){ `?

Comment: Now I feel stupid. Sorry. And why does it only run through it twice then? Step 4 should only be called once, but for some reason this is the only step that goes twice even though the code is almost exactly identical to the other 3...

Comment: I will suggest you to debug your code. I cant tell you why just by looking at this code snippet. But the block where are you printing values should take a closer look.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, the last two outputs, where 8 and 9 are added are wrong.

The problem is, that you keep searching the grid whith the updated numLocation and this numLocation is in a part of the grid, which was not searched jet.

The solution would be to break the outer loops (the ones with r and c) after you found the numLocation and made your changes.

To do this, you need to add a label before the first for:

```
label: for (int r = 0; r < gridRow-1; r++){...
```

and insert this after the innermost for-loop (with the i)

```
break label;
```